# getting nearest past date records on sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following table:

```
id  dr          cr     balance      txn_date
 1   0.00      0.00     31895532.96 12/20/2013
 2  15000.00    0.00    31880532.96 12/20/2013
 3  102120.00   0.00    31778412.96 12/20/2013
 4  15250.00    0.00    31763162.96 12/20/2013
 5  75000.00    0.00    25761370.96 12/22/2013
 6  98600.00    0.00    25662770.96 12/22/2013
 7  71460.00    0.00    25591310.96 12/22/2013
 8  518400.00   0.00    25072910.96 12/22/2013
 9  35000.00    0.00    25037910.96 12/22/2013
```

I need to find the opening balance when the date is inputted . For example when `12/20/2013` is inputted then opening balance is `31895532.96`.

It is not necessary to have transaction on daily basis. Here too we have no transaction on `21st December 2013`, in that case we need to take balance of last transaction of `12/20/2013` i.e `31763162.96`. Any ideas how to implement it?

I did the following for `12/20/2013`:

```
select top 1 balance
from banks
where txn_date = '12/20/2013' order by id
```

now when I come to `12/21/2013` there is no transaction on that date. So the last transaction of previous date(not necessarily yesterday it could be any date depending on transaction date) should be  balance i.e `31763162.96`:

```
select top 1 balance
from banks
where txn_date <= '12/21/2013' order by id desc
```

It returned last transaction of previous date of `12.21.2013`

How to merge two above queries to satisfy both conditions?

Comment: Why you are lost i don't understand which one you are maintaining are you talking about sum(dr)=balance??

Comment: no there is 'balance'  column

Comment: So what is the relation bet last updated and current?

Comment: show ur effort possibly in terms of SQL query u tried so far
if u are only storing the date as per your post, you wont be able to find opening balance as a particular date is repeated, u actually need to store time within same date column, only then you can use order by clause, that sorts the results

Comment: Please explain why your example is not working for you. What do you get? what do you expect to get?

Answer (score 0):

You did not supply any information about why `31895532.96` should be the output for an `12/20/2013` input. In your example you have multiple records with the same `txn_date` value.
In the following query I select an arbitrary value among the records that satisfy the `txn_date` condition.

```
SELECT TOP 1 balance       
FROM banks
WHERE txn_date = @argumentDate
```

In this example `@argumentDate` is any date for comparison (`12/20/2013` in your question).

**Edit**:
Assuming your `txn_date` column is DateTime Column and not just a string you can use:

```
SELECT TOP 1 balance
FROM banks
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY , txn_date , @argumentDate ) <=0
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(DAY , txn_date , @argumentDate ) DESC
```

Comment: . it will return balance when there is transaction on that @argumentDate

Comment: @timus2001 I have edited the answer as per your edits

Answer (score 0):

Using CTE can get the logic

```
with cte (DR,CR,Balance,TxnDate,RowID ) as
(
    select DR,CR,Balance,TxnDate,Row_number() over (PARTITION by txndate order by txndate desc) as RowID 
    from Trans
) 
select top 1 Balance 
from cte 
where TxnDate = case when @TXNDATE = '12/20/2013' then  (select top 1 TxnDate from Cte where @TXNDATE = '12/20/2013') 
                  when @TXNDATE > '12/20/2013' then (select top 1 TxnDate from Cte where TXNDATE='12/20/2013' ) end
ORDER BY 
    case when @TXNDATE = '12/20/2013' then RowID end ASC,
    case when @TXNDATE > '12/20/2013' then RowID end Desc
```